# Guidance for building a Google chrome extension in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, scrapy

I would like to build a chrome extension in python(because Javascript would be completely new to me!). There are multiple things that I want to do and finding a hard time wrapping my head around to understand if it is possible and what tools would be needed.

The extension would display the results of web scraping(using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)) a page. Scraping the page and updating the results on the extension need to be done every 5 minutes.

I do know that [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) is one of the options, but it isn't clear to me if I can use third party apps like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) in the Google chrome extension.

Anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: I think Chrome extensions can only be developed in JavaScript. Ok, pyjs may let you translate your Python code to js, but if you want to parse HTML jQuery simplifies it a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048436/chrome-extension-in-python)

Comment: Could [Brython](http://brython.info/) be a possible way to accomplish this?  Of course, that is python translated to JavaScript, but from the developer's perspective it feels like writing Python.

Comment: @ChrisP: That might help a lot more than the close votes !! Thank you

Comment: I think you're going to haver a LOT Of problems trying to shoehorn Python into a Chrome Extension. You'll probably get a basic Python script to work, but I can't image libraries like Scrapy would work out of the box with just Pyjs. If JavaScript really scares you, perhaps CoffeeScript is a viable altarnative? http://jhchabran.com/blog/2011/12/17/build-a-chrome-extension-with-coffeescript/